# Below code give me error like "The view home.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to add an edit button to my project and gives me an error.

This is my `views.py` file, i made display and delete function but both are working perfect.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import List
from .forms import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages


def edit(request, list_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)

        form = ListForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Task Has Been Edited...!!!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
        return render(request, 'home/edit.html', {'item': item})
```

This is my `urls.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),    #home page
    path('delete/<list_id>', views.delete, name="delete"),    #delete the task
    path('edit/<list_id>', views.edit, name="edit"),    #edit page
]
```

This is my `edit.html` in which i extend `base.html` file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}    #extending base template

{% block content %}

    {% if item %}

    <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 mt-2">
            <input type="search" name="item" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ item.task }}" size="130"
                   value="{{ item.task }}">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Edit</button>
    </form>

    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

when i hit edit button, which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError at /edit/3
The view home.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

When I click the edit button after I edit my task it gives me the error.

Comment: What happens if the request method is POST and the form isn't valid?

Comment: @JohnGordon i Don't Know

Comment: In that case the function does not return any value, so it returns None by default, which matches the error you're getting.  You need to handle that case.

Comment: @JohnGordon How to handle that case..??

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def edit(request, list_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Task Has Been Edited...!!!')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Fill the form properly...!!!")

    item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)        
    return render(request, 'home/edit.html', {'item': item})
```